# Normal Linux use Xorg like graphical server for desktop but android does not then what uses android..?

Tags: android

How android Graphics work? can any one explain please. which graphics server does android use.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android uses mainly two technologies: SurfaceFlinger at the window manager level, and Skia (or optionally OpenGL) at the application level.

SurfaceFlinger is used to create surfaces, which are the "windows" displayed by the window manager.

Skia is a 2D rendering engine. An application uses Skia to render the content on each of its surfaces (windows).

An application can optionally use OpenGL ES to render into its surfaces for 3D.